# Statistics on subsets of a dataset

Tags: loops, r-markdown, apply

Looking for more R-ish ways of implementing a "for" loop with "subset", that will lend itself to implementation in R Markdown

I have a large dataset, that can be summarised as:
StudentID, Unit, TutorialID, SemesterID, Mark, Grade

I have written the following code, which seems to work OK.  This reflects my background as an imperative programmer of long ago (and the fact that I am self-taught in R). Partly, I am curious as to how to write the "sequential application of a group of functions" to "successive subsets" in a way that is more R-ish.

```
ListOfUnits <- unique (Dataset$Unit)
for (val in ListOfUnits) {
    EachUnit <- subset(Dataset, Unit == val)
boxplot(Mark ~ TutorialID, ylim=c(0,100), data=EachUnit,outline=TRUE,main=val)
    aggregate(x= EachUnit$Mark, by = list(EachUnit$Campus), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
aggregate(x= EachUnit$Mark, by = list(EachUnit$Campus), FUN=sd, na.rm=TRUE)
if (nrow(count(EachUnit$TutorialID)) >= 2) {
    # Here I have code to run an ANOVA and the Tukey HSD test for any difference
    # between means among tutorial groups, culminating in
    bar.group(pp$groups,ylim=c(0,100),density=400,border="black",main=val)
}
else {
    }
}
```

I have also tried my hand at creating an R Markdown script to genearte a report on the multitude of units that exist.  What seemed a promising approach involves knitr::knit_expand(file = "file_location"   ... early efforts seemed to be good, but when I included "for" or "if" statements in either the 'parent' or 'child' file, it either generated errors or did not run as expected.

My conclusion is that the basic routine is insufficiently "R-ish", hence the question above.

But an immediate follow-on question is "how to achieve the above in R Markdown, so as to produce a report"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following prototype does the job:

```
Unit_Statistics <- function(Unit) {
  boxplot(Mark ~ Campus, ylim=c(0,100),data=Unit,outline=TRUE,main=Unit$Unit[1])
}

bitbucket <- Dataset %>% group_by(Unit) %>% do(Stats=Unit_Statistics(.))
```